# Updating date within bar button Item

Tags: swift, date, segue, option-type, uisplitviewcontroller

So I have a splitViewController withe a tableView and detailView. What I want is to have a button within the detailView, when pressed, to add two weeks to a bar button item within the tableView(masterview). I have all the segues working and set up, but whenever I run it the optional

Here is the segue that runs within the detailView

```
 var textMC = MasterViewController()

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if ((segue.destination as? UISplitViewController) != nil) {
        textMC.sim()
    }
```

Then within the masterView

```
    func sim() {
    let previousDate = dateLabel.title
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
    let previousDateFormated : Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: previousDate!)
    let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 14, to: (previousDateFormated)! )
    let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    dateLabel.title = stringDate
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 632880000)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
    let result = formatter.string(from: date)
    dateLabel.title = result

update()
```

}

The viewDidLoad func does make the initial dateLabel.title the correct date and the sim function does run, but its method returns the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" referring to dateLabel.title. I don't understand why its nil and how to fix this issue. Is it because although I have a dateLabel.title the actual dateLabel is nil? Please tell me how I can fix this. Thanks

Comment: I cannot see any code setting an actual `MasterViewController` to the property `textMC`. How are doing that?

Comment: var textMC = MasterViewController() this?

Comment: That code instantiate a completely useless empty `MasterViewController`. You should better declare it as `var textMC: MasterViewController?` than instantiating such useless thing. If you have no code other than the line, you call `sim()` on the empty `MasterViewController` where all IBOutlets are not set, thus causes "unexpectedly found nil" crash.

Comment: Please show your code to transition to your detail view controller, you may need to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 var textMC = MasterViewController()
```

Is wrong. That will create a brand new instance of `MasterViewController()` with absolutely no view contents. You should never do that.

instead, add a segue from your current view controler to your `MasterViewController`'s scene in your storyboard, give it an identifier, and use

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourMasterVCIdentifierHere")
```

Then implement prepareForSegue something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let dest = segue.destination as? MasterViewController {
       textMC
    }
}
```